# I'm trying to write a program that'll password protect a pdf for a user. The user needs to be able to upload the pdf and download a protected one

Tags: java, spring-boot

in my attempts, i would either get a corrupt file or an unprotected pfd, here's the code im using:

//upload files method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<List<String>> uploadFiles(@RequestParam("files")List<MultipartFile> multipartFiles) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    List<String> filenames = new ArrayList<>();
    for (MultipartFile file : multipartFiles){
        String filename = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());
        Path fileStorage = get(DIRECTORY, filename).toAbsolutePath().normalize();
        copy(file.getInputStream(), fileStorage, REPLACE_EXISTING);

        File f = new File(String.valueOf(fileStorage));
        if(!f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {
            try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fis);
                pdfReader.setUnethicalReading(true);
                WriterProperties writerProperties = new WriterProperties();
                writerProperties.setStandardEncryption(OWNER_PASSWORD.getBytes(),
                        USER_PASSWORD.getBytes(), EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_PRINTING,
                        EncryptionConstants.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
                PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(new FileOutputStream("Protected_"+DIRECTORY), writerProperties);
                PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader, pdfWriter);
                pdfDocument.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        filenames.add(filename);

    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(filenames);
}
```

any help with this problem would be appreciated. because i need my users to upload a normal pdf file and be able download the same pdf file with password protection

Comment: What library & version are you using for PDF creation?

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
   <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
   <version>7.1.9</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: itextpdf kernel version 7.1.9

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your suggestion of breaking it down, creating an encrypt method helped in producing the protected file.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> uploadFiles(@RequestParam("files")List<MultipartFile> multipartFiles) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        List<String> filenames = new ArrayList<>();
        for (MultipartFile file : multipartFiles){
            String filename = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());
            Path fileStorage = get(DIRECTORY, filename).toAbsolutePath().normalize();
            copy(file.getInputStream(), fileStorage, REPLACE_EXISTING);
            encrypt(fileStorage, filename);
            filenames.add(filename);

        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(filenames);
    }

    public static void encrypt(Path src, String filename){
            try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(String.valueOf(src));
                PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fis);
                pdfReader.setUnethicalReading(true);
                WriterProperties writerProperties = new WriterProperties();
                writerProperties.setStandardEncryption(OWNER_PASSWORD.getBytes(),
                        USER_PASSWORD.getBytes(), EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_PRINTING,
                        EncryptionConstants.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
                PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(new FileOutputStream(filename), writerProperties);
                PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader, pdfWriter);
                pdfDocument.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).